# Black stripes all over the model after texture painting

Tags: texture-painting

After texture painting my model, when I switch to render view, it shows these black stripes all over the model, whereas in the texture viewport it's fine. Why?

[image: Texture in viewport]

[image: Texture in render view]

Comment: Could we see a fever, or screenshot of render view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it, with the help of cycles render. Just created a material (diffuse) node and joined the uv image texture to it.